# Adding Family to friends on steam

Tags: steam

Been trying to add my brother as a friend who was already in family on steam once I made my account but when I try to add him his name doesn't come up, anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: You have to search for his profile, click the button to friend him, then he has to accept it.

Comment: @Keavon why not post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for other profiles in the Steam Client has not always been as easy as it should be. A fail-safe way to find your friend and add him, is be asking him to go to his profile in his browser. Then he'll copy his URL (it should look something like `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198017813554/`), and send it to you. Then you can open this URL in your browser (remember to log in), and add him there.

If the problem still persists, please try [Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/).

Comment: I just want to emphasize that IMHO this is the best solution. The search function of Steam is really buggy and I often could not find friends even though I entered their names exactly. The profile ID is unique, so it has to work.

Comment: The problem is that Steam tends to search by username rather than display name.  Which you can't ever change.  Really old steam accounts use email addresses, so my steam username is an email address I haven't used in 7+ years.